# Как проверить введенную строку на соответствие формату

Tags: c#, строки

Скажем у меня есть строка формата #AAA#АА## (где # - является цифрой, A - любой буквой русского языка), то как проверить введённую пользователем строку на соответствие этому формату?

> я начинающий программист, пожалуйста не ругайте если некорректно выражаю свои задумки

Comment: [Регулярные выражения](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)

Comment: Можно в цикле посимвольно проверить или регуляркой.

Comment: Регуляркой, например такой: \d{1}[а-яА-ЯёЁ]{3}\d[а-яА-ЯёЁ]{2}\d{2} (думаю можно и проще)